# Copy operator not working in Quick Fast C++

Tags: c++, fix-protocol

Now currently I am working on copy operator. What I understand from all the document and other material available on net is that Quickfast maintains a dictionary which is used by multiples entries  within a UDP message to check the previous value.

eg:  Lets say in the below given template we can have multiple MDEntries depending upon NoMDEntries tag value. Lets say we have 2 as the value .
What I did was ,  I put the value of MDEntryType (with copy oprerator ) as 1 (some random value)  in the first entry, but for the second entry I did not put any value.
After I decode the message the value of MDEntryType should be 1 for both the entries.

Is my understanding correct ?

> ```
> <template dictionary="1" id="1" name="MDIncRefreshSample_1">
>  <string id="35" name="MessageType">
>     <constant value="X"></constant>
>  </string>     <string id="49" name="SenderCompID">
>     <constant value="Client"></constant>
> </string>     <string id="56" name="TargetCompID">
>     <constant value="Server"></constant>
> </string>     <uint32 id="34" name="MsgSeqNum"></uint32>
> <uint64 id="52" name="SendingTime"></uint64>
> <sequence name="MDEntries">
>     <length id="268" name="NoMDEntries"></length>
>     <uint32 id="279" name="MDUpdateAction">
>         <copy value="1"></copy>
>     </uint32>
>     <string id="269" name="MDEntryType">
>         <copy value="0"></copy>
>     </string>
>     <uint32 id="278" name="MDEntryID"></uint32>
>     <uint32 id="48" name="SecurityID">
>         <delta></delta>
>     </uint32>
>     <decimal id="270" name="MDEntryPx">
>         <exponent>
>             <default value="-2"></default>
>         </exponent>
>         <mantissa>
>             <delta></delta>
>         </mantissa>
>     </decimal>
>     <int32 id="271" name="MDEntrySize">
>         <delta></delta>
>     </int32>
>     <string id="37" name="OrderID"></string>
>     <uint32 id="273" name="MDEntryTime">
>         <copy></copy>
>     </uint32>
>  </sequence>
>  </template>
> ```

Now when I try to implement the above in my code, I am not able to copy the value in the second entry.
Here is the snippet of the code I used (help  taken from testRoundTrip.cpp)

Template Created :

> ```
>   <templates> 
>     <template dictionary="InstrumentReferenceData" 
>      name="InstrumentReferenceData" id="3">  
>      <typeRef name="instrumentreferencedata"/>  
>      <uInt32 name="timestamp" id="52"> <delta/>    </uInt32>  
>      <uInt32 name="srcId" id="50">      <copy/>    </uInt32>   
>      <uInt32 name="seqNum" id="34">      <increment value="1"/>    </uInt32> 
>      <uInt32 name="isix" id="48">      <delta/>    </uInt32>  
>     <string name="isin" id="455">      <delta/>    </string> 
>     <string name="exchId" id="207">      <copy/>    </string>  
>     <string name="instGrp" id="1151">      <copy/>    </string>
>     <string name="instTypCod" id="461">      <copy/>    </string>    
>     <string name="currCode" id="15">      <copy/>    </string>    
>     <decimal name="ticSiz" id="969">      <delta/>    </decimal>   
>     <uInt32 name="setId" id="TBD">      <copy/>    </uInt32>  
>      <sequence name="MDFeedTypes">    
>      <length name="noOfStreams" id="1141"/>     
>      <string name="streamType" id="1022">      <copy dictionary="template" />      
>     </string>   
>     <string name="streamService">      <copy/>      </string>        
>      <string name="inetAddr">        <delta/>      </string>       
>   <uInt32 name="port" id="TBD">        <delta/>      </uInt32>        
>   <uInt32 name="mktDepth" id="264" presence="optional"/>   </uInt32>       
>   <uInt32 name="mdBookType" id="1021" presence="optional"/>   </uInt32>
>     </sequence>
>     </template>
>     </templates>
> ```

Message creation plus encoding and decoding:  (I have poulated the value in streamtype field only once)

```
 Messages::MessagePtr msg(new Messages::Message(templateRegistry->maxFieldCount()));
  msg->addField(identity_timestamp, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(1));

  msg->addField(identity_srcId, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(2));

  msg->addField(identity_seqNum, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(3));

  msg->addField(identity_isix, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(4));

  msg->addField(identity_isin, Messages::FieldAscii::create("isin"));

  msg->addField(identity_exchId, Messages::FieldAscii::create("exchId"));

  msg->addField(identity_instGrp, Messages::FieldAscii::create("instGrp"));

  msg->addField(identity_instTypCod, Messages::FieldAscii::create("instTypCod"));

  msg->addField(identity_currCode, Messages::FieldAscii::create("currCode"));

  msg->addField(identity_ticSiz, Messages::FieldDecimal::create(Decimal(123, -1)));

  msg->addField(identity_setId, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(5));

  lengthIdentity.setId("1141");
  Messages::SequencePtr sequence_MDFeedTypes(new Messages::Sequence(lengthIdentity, 2));
  Messages::FieldSetPtr entry(new Messages::FieldSet(6)); // todo Hardcoded 6?

  entry->addField(identity_streamType, Messages::FieldAscii::create("streamType"));    // Populated the value 1st time

  entry->addField(identity_streamService, Messages::FieldAscii::create("streamService"));

  entry->addField(identity_inetAddr, Messages::FieldAscii::create("inetAddr.com"));

  entry->addField(identity_port, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(2222));

  entry->addField(identity_mktDepth, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(10));



  sequence_MDFeedTypes->addEntry(Messages::FieldSetCPtr(entry));

  entry.reset(new Messages::FieldSet(6));

  entry->addField(identity_streamType, Messages::FieldAscii::create(""));     // Did not Populate the value 2nd time

  entry->addField(identity_streamService, Messages::FieldAscii::create(""));

  entry->addField(identity_inetAddr, Messages::FieldAscii::create("inetAddr.org"));

  entry->addField(identity_port, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(2224));

  entry->addField(identity_mdBookType, Messages::FieldUInt32::create(3));



  sequence_MDFeedTypes->addEntry(Messages::FieldSetCPtr(entry));

  msg->addField(identity_MDFeedTypes, Messages::FieldSequence::create(sequence_MDFeedTypes));

  Codecs::Encoder encoder(templateRegistry);
  Codecs::DataDestination destination;
  template_id_t templId = 3; // from the XML above
  encoder.encodeMessage(destination, templId, *msg);
  std::string fastString;
  destination.toString(fastString);
  std::cout<<"fastString is "<<fastString<<std::endl;

  destination.clear();

  Codecs::Decoder decoder(templateRegistry);
  Codecs::DataSourceString source(fastString);
  Codecs::SingleMessageConsumer consumer;
  Codecs::GenericMessageBuilder builder(consumer);
  decoder.decodeMessage(source, builder);

  Messages::Message & msgOut(consumer.message());

        Messages::MessageFormatter formatter(std::cout);
        formatter.formatMessage(msgOut);                                   // I have made some printing changes to print the ouptut per tag 

  validateMessage1(msgOut);


  encoder.reset();
  encoder.encodeMessage(destination, templId, msgOut);
  std::string reencoded;
  destination.toString(reencoded);

  destination.clear();
```

I am able to encode and successfully decode the message, but the value is not getting copied in the second entry (streamType tag).
Here is my decoded ouput:

```
 1st entry:
 streamType[1022]=streamType                  
 streamService[]=streamService
 inetAddr[]=inetAddr.com
 port[TBD]= 2045


 2nd entry:
streamType[1022]=                     //value not copied
streamService[]=
 inetAddr[]=inetAddr.org
 port[TBD]= 2046
```

Could you please let us know, if we are making a mistake somewhere. I am very new to this :)

I have following queries too :

1/ **Do we need to explicitly need to enable/disable dictionary in quickfast ? (In FIX we could do that with flag, DataDictionary = Y/N).** 
Also  in the template created above , I found this line:

```
<string name="streamType" id="1022">      <copy dictionary="template" />      </string>
```

Is it neccesary to give dictionary name while using operators and how are they related?

2/ Do we also need to explicitly mention that PMAP bits are required?

**Codecs::PresenceMap pmap(1);**     // I came across this function, so I got this doubt whether  we need to explicitly mention about pmap.